# Select multiple rows in issue list

Tags: trac, issue-tracking

Is there way to select multiple issue in issue-list in Trac, like it is possible in Jira or Redmine, and perform any operations with them? Like changing status, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trac 1.0 supports operations on multiple tickets (which it calls "Batch Modify") from any "custom query" results list, but not from the "report" views.

For older trac versions, the functionality is available as a plugin: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/BatchModifyPlugin

Here's a screenshot of the plugin UI:

[image: BatchModify plugin UI screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are describing batch modify functionality.

In older versions of Trac you could install and use the [Batch Modify Plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/BatchModifyPlugin) to do this.

In more recent versions of Trac (starting at 1.0) this feature is now core functionality - see the [#525](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/525) enhancement ticket and the [TracBatchModify](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBatchModify) wiki page on [trac edgewall](http://trac.edgewall.org/).

There is also a [GridModifyPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GridModifyPlugin) which allows you to edit ticket field values inline which may be useful.